# How do you force the focus on the page in Firefox using ExtensionAPI?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am creating a Firefox extension that overrides the new tab page and show something else. However, I noticed that when I create a new tab, the focus goes into the address bar of the browser.

There is a search box within the new page and I would like to put focus on it instead of the address bar. I already have a `searchInput.focus()` in the page and it gets focused as intended in Chrome.

How can I do the same with Firefox using WebExtension API?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug which prevents this from working when out-of-process extensions are enabled, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1415860

Follow the bug to stay up to date, if you find a workaround for this issue let me know or write a comment into the bug report.